# SSRS Printing sub report for each record

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

Is there a SSRS guru that can help me please?

I have a report that generates a tabular list of Claims as follows:

[image]

The dataset contains a single table and multiple records with a RecordID, Carnet Number and Claim Number. The RecordID is not shown on the report.

I then have a different report, lets call it "**LETTER**", that is in a letter format:

[image]

The LETTER report prints a letter containing information for a single Claim and its content is extracted from the database by using the RecordID.

I have added the LETTER report as a sub report and it is linked to the main report via the RecordID.

***Requirment***
The first report must generate as normal and list all the Claims in the dataset. The subreport LETTER must then generate for EVERY claim shown on the first report. Each LETTER must be on a seperate page as it will be printed on an official company letterhead. No direct printing to a printer is allowed which means the reports must be shown as a single report for the user. The default SSRS page navigation etc functions will be available.

***Problem***
The subreport LETTER must be generated for each RecordID. Currently it is only generating for the first RecordID.

How do I ensure that there is a LETTER for each claim that is listed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're going to need to add all of the elements of the letter into a list item and group by the RecordID field.  I did something similar for a small report in the image below.  Basically, add a list item and set the dataset to match your claims dataset in the `Tablix Properties`.  Then, open the `Group Properties`, group on RecordID, navigate to the `Page Breaks` tab and add a page break between each instance of a group.  This should produce a new letter for each `RecordID`.

[image]

Comment: thanx Steve-0169, Your suggestion worked perfectly !